# How to reach the main class in a parent object?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm writing a simple card game for iPhone. The cards are in cardset containers which are subclasses of UIScrollView. The cardsets are in a desk container which is a UIViewController. In the cards i overrode the touchesEnded method but I cannot access the main class which contains the desk. How to do it? Should I give a pointer to all the cards to reach the main? Or can I get the parent container?

Comment: what did you mean with "main class" the cardset container or the UIViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a reference in the cards.

In the cards interface, define something like

```
@interface cards
{
    DeskController *deskp;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) DeskController *deskp;
```

When you create cards, assign the desk reference

```
- (void) setupCards
{
    CardController *card = // allocate card
    card.deskp = self;
}
```

In cards dealloc() or viewDidUnload, set it to nil

```
self.deskp = nil;
```